# Check all $_POST Variable at once

Tags: php

instead of checking all my post variables from a form one at a time is there any way to run one check to atleast verify that they are not empty something like

```
if(!isset(ALL $_POST)){
echo "one of your fields is not completed.";
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create an array of required fields and loop through that

```
$required_fields = array("name", "address", "phone", "email");
foreach ($require_fields as $field) {
    if (!strlen($_POST[$field])) {
        echo "$field cannot be empty";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**No** because how would your program know which should exist?

However, if you have a list of fields that are expected, you can easily write a function to check.  I called it `array_keys_exist` because it does the exact same thing as [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists) except with multiple keys:

```
function array_keys_exist($keys, $array) {
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $array)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$expectedFields = array('name', 'email');

$success = array_keys_exist($expectedFields, $_POST);
```

Comment: Don't know why no ones up voted this answer. Thanks!

Comment: with these key exist in array condition, i am also checking && empty($array[$key]) but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done like the way you're thinking (as PHP has no way of knowing what values there should be).

But you could it like this:

```
<?php
  $POSTvaluesToCheck = array('write', 'here', 'all', 'the', 'values', 'that', 'are', 'mandatory', 'to', 'exist');

  foreach($POSTvaluesToCheck as $key) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$key]) {
      echo $key . ' not set correctly!';
    }
  }
?>
```